# multiple tinymce textareas

Tags: html, tinymce

I use tinymce for a webpage that dynamically generates at least 5 texts. 
The configuration I use only works on the first `textarea` unfortunately.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    height : "300",
    mode : "exact",
    elements : "content",
    theme : "simple",
    editor_selector : "mceEditor",
    ...

<textarea class="mceEditor" name="content" rows="15" cols="40">content</textarea>
```

What's the configuration to enable tinymce editing in **all** `textarea`'s.

Comment: How do we enable tinymce excluding specific items in a class ? I could handle ids. I have posted another question -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55181418/multiple-tinymce-textareas-excluding-first

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're using "exact" mode you'll need to specify the ids of the elements you wish to convert to editors.

```
function initMCEexact(e){
  tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "exact",
    elements : e,
    ...
  });
}
// add textarea element with id="content" to document
initMCEexact("content");
// add textarea element with id="content2" to document
initMCEexact("content2");
// add textarea element with id="content3" to document
initMCEexact("content3");
```

Or, you can use the "textarea" mode, which indiscriminately applies the editor to all textareas.

```
function initMCEall(){
  tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    ...
  });
}
// add all textarea elements to document
initMCEall();
```

Just remember that if you're creating textareas dynamically, you will need to call tinyMCE.init() *after* creating the elements, because they need to be existing for tinyMCE to be able to convert them.

[Here is the documentation on modes](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x%3amode).

Answer (score 3):

For TinyMCE 4.0 you have to use a selector or defining a tinymce.init object/method for each desired configuration (https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/multiple-editors/).

For example, this is a page with 3 editors:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#myeditable-h1',
    toolbar: 'undo redo'
  });
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '.standard-editor'
  });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post">
    <h1 id="myeditable-h1">This Title Can Be Edited If You Click Here</h1>
  </form>

  <form method="post">
    <div id="myeditable-div1" class="standard-editor">
      <p>This section1 of content can be edited...</p>
    </div>

    <div id="myeditable-div2" class="standard-editor">
      <p>This section2 of content can be edited...</p>
    </div>

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use different mode in your configuration. For example mode: "specific_textareas" to work for all textarea with a given class which is specified in the editor_selector parameter.

In order to work on all textareas with class mceEditor you can use this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector : "mceEditor",
    .....
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all sensibly. It converts this selector AND ALL OTHER TEXTAREAS except for those with a class specified by "editor_deselector". So in other words "editor_selector" does nothing and only "editor_deselector" works. If you leave out "editor_deselector" it just always selects all textareas.

Answer (score 2):

use class in selector
i have two or more textarea that i want init those with tiny int so

```
<textarea class="mytextarea"></textarea>
<textarea class="mytextarea"></textarea>
.
.
.
```

in init tinyint code:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea.mytextarea',
    plugins : 'advlist autolink link lists preview table code pagebreak',
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: how to get value of a specific element ?

Answer (score 1):

In the `tinymce.init()` function, just add a second selector, separated by a comma, to the `selector:` key:

```
selector: 'textarea#editor1, #editor-the-seconde'
```

We can add multiple tinyMCE textareas like above

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

According to [tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:selector](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:selector), selector is the recommended way of selecting what elements should be editable.

For all textarea elements, as requested:

```
selector: "textarea",
```

Or more elegantly, only those elements with a specific CSS tag:

```
selector: "textarea.editme",

<textarea class="editme">
```