# multiple tinymce textareas excluding first

Tags: tinymce

How do we use tinymce in a class used multiple times, except the first time ?

I was looking at [multiple tinymce textareas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509484/multiple-tinymce-textareas) but could not find fully as what I wanted.

I have `.wp-editor-area` used multiple times, but do not want the mce in the first instance.

I had used :

```
<script>
  tinymce.init({
    selector: ".wp-editor-area"
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effectively you cannot "skip" any elements that match the selector's value - there is no configuration to do that.

Can you add a second class?  Do the textareas in question also have an `id`?  If you don't want to have one of these textareas match the selector you will need to find a selector that does not match that first textarea.