# TinyMce isn't editable and clickable on dynamic created textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tinymce, textarea

the scenario I have is to by clicking add button i generate new textarea, its like repeater fields.
I want to set Tinymce on every newly created textarea and all other existing already.
the issue i am having is the existing textarea is working fine, but the others generated dynamically are not working properly. The TinyMCE textarea is showing but it is completely not clickable nor editable.

HTML Code:

```
<!-- empty hidden one for jQuery -->
<tr class="empty-row screen-reader-text">
<tr class="empty-row screen-reader-text">
    <td>
         <input type="text" class="widefat" name="index[]" />
    </td>
    
    <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="name[]" /></td>

    <td><input type="file" class="widefat" name="attachment[]" />
    <input type="hidden" name="attachment_current[]" >
    </td>
    
    <td>
    <textarea class="widefat tiny" name="anno_text[]" ></textarea>
    </td>
    
    <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="url[]" value="http://" /></td>
      
    <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<p><a id="add-row" class="button" href="#">Add another</a></p>
```

Jquery code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
     $.fn.extend({
initTiny: function() {
  tinymce.init({
    mode: "textareas",
    height: 100
  });
}
});
    
    
    $( '#add-row' ).on('click', function() {
        var row = $( '.empty-row.screen-reader-text' ).clone(true);
        row.removeClass( 'empty-row screen-reader-text' );
        row.insertBefore( '#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody>tr:last' );

     $("textarea", row).initTiny();
        return false;
    });

 $(".tiny").initTiny();

    $( '.remove-row' ).on('click', function() {
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

what i have got in result i'm attaching an image.

[image]

the 1st tinymce editor works fine but after that not a signle tinymce editor is clickable

Comment: This might help first, but it's older: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509484/multiple-tinymce-textareas

Comment: @Twisty no this didnt work too, actually i am having a tinymce editor but it isnt editable and clickable for newly generated textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    initTiny: function() {
      console.log("Init TinyMCE");
      tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea.tiny",
        height: 100
      });
    }
  });

  $("#add-row").click(function() {
    var row = $(".row-template").html();
    console.log("Row Cloned");
    $(row).appendTo('#repeatable-fieldset-one > tbody');
    console.log("Row Appended", $("#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody tr").length);
    $(".tiny").initTiny();
  });

  $("#add-row").trigger("click");

  $("#repeatable-fieldset-one").on("click", ".remove-row", function() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove the Row?")) {
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/5.10.0/tinymce.min.js" integrity="sha512-XNYSOn0laKYg55QGFv1r3sIlQWCAyNKjCa+XXF5uliZH+8ohn327Ewr2bpEnssV9Zw3pB3pmVvPQNrnCTRZtCg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/5.10.0/jquery.tinymce.min.js" integrity="sha512-nmHWouzLZ3EkXUiXVLpRy/scUPyOOwWkAZ6p8GJnswtVIfSgQ6dFjfCv4VrUA9YgutCRqUDyjHGfQ+/3OEbH4Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<template class="row-template">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="widefat" name="index[]" />
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="name[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="file" class="widefat" name="attachment[]" />
      <input type="hidden" name="attachment_current[]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <textarea class="widefat tiny" name="anno_text[]"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="url[]" value="http://" /></td>
    <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
  </tr>
</template>

<table id="repeatable-fieldset-one">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p><a id="add-row" class="button" href="#">Add another</a></p>
```

See More:

- [multiple tinymce textareas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509484/multiple-tinymce-textareas)
- https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/Configuration3x/Configuration3x@mode/
- https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/

Comment: I have used your solution but it still having same issue it do create a tinymce editor for me but after 1st one all are unclickable.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example The Example you posted is missing many element, such as `$('.empty-row.screen-reader-text')`

Comment: or we ca say it only happens when we click add another button.

Comment: I have updated my question kindly have a look at it now ?

Comment: No one gonna take a look ?

Comment: @TalhaArif this still does not appear to be complete example.

Comment: @TalhaArif I think the issue is that you have Cloned the TinyMCE element along with it's ID and other parts. I think what you need is a `<template>`.

Comment: @TalhaArif updated answer with a template that I think will work as you intended.